# Use dropdown (from range) to enter data. Change dropdown items. Data is now stale (how to reflect changes?)

Tags: google-sheets

### In Summary:

I created a `dropdown (from range)`, used the dropdown to populate data in a range of cells. Next I changed one of the items in the `dropdown`. Expanding the `dropdown` now displays the new items, but the data that I had already entered still shows the old item (along with an error indicator). Is there a way to get the cells to auto-update instead?

### In More Detail:

I created a `dropdown (from range)` over `C1:C5` using `A1:A5` for the dataSource. Works as expected.

[image]

I move on and begin entering data using the `dropdown`. Smooth sailing.

[image]

Uh oh! All the strawberries have spoiled, but no worries there are extra KIWI to substitute with. I update the `dropdown` by replacing `strawberry` with `KIWI` in cell `A5`. The `dropdown` now includes `KIWI`.

However, my data-entry is broken. `C5` does hint that there's a problem with the red triangle.

[image]

Sure, I could go hunt down and fix all the cells with a warning. But I sure would prefer it if any `strawberry` cells in `A:A` automatically updated to reflect the change to `KIWI`. Like if the `dropdown` worked with references instead of values.

I have been able to discover a way to accomplish this. The Data Validation rules don't seem to support this. I spent some time trying to write formulas using combinations of LOOKUP/ADDRESS/MATCH/INDIRECT, etc..., but I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of directly achieving what you want with formulas as the described behaviour (of generating an error if the source values for a dropdown are changed) is by design - when you select a value, you select that actual value (not the index of that value in a list).

A formula-based workaround would be to create a visible source table for your dropdown like this:

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | orange |
| 3 | banana |
| 4 | cherry |
| 5 | strawberry |

Then use column A (i.e. the list indexes) as the source for your dropdowns elsewhere on the sheet, and in the column alongside your dropdowns use `index` (or `chooserows`) to display the chosen options based on the selected indexes. If you then change values in column B of the source table, these will be automatically reflected in the dropdown list.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain and include a starter. I appreciate that.